Get custom attribute from stacktrace
I created a custom attribute for that method to determine if instance was created for use as a argument for a particular method.
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class IAAttr: System.Attribute {
    public string desc { get; }

    public IAAttr(string t) => desc = t;
}

[IAAttr("instance_add")]
public void instance_add(params Object[] instances) {
    //Do something...
}


[Object's constructor]
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();

for (int i=1; i<DEPTH; i=i+1) {

    if (st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().CustomAttributes.Count() > 0) {

        
        //if custom attribute exists, do not execute below


        return;
    }
}

Create();

What code should I write to detect custom attributes in the next stack frame?
When a function with an attribute is executed, two custom attributes are detected, and the following types are detected.
[0]{System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute}
[1]{System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute}
Both custom attributes appear to be created during the debug process.
The following attempts were all failed,
st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().
GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IAAttr), true).FirstOrDefault(); //->null

foreach (Attribute attr in st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes()) {

    if ((Type)attr.TypeId == typeof(IAAttr)) {

        //System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute
        //System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute
    }
}


What is the problem you are trying to solve? I have the strong feeling that a custom attribute might not be what you actually want to be using in the first place.

I'm developing a game framework based on mono games. I defined "Room" that have some data of Instances, backgroundcolor, & etc. for adding some data of instance, I defined method "instance_add(params Object[] instances)" It recieves new instances and add to private list in Room. When Room changes, refer to list of Room, create new instances.

Sounds like you should take advantage of the C# type system, then. Do you happen to come from JavaScript or something else that's rather type-less?

When adding data, Object's custom initializer method (I defined it "Create()", it executes when instance create; don't need to be executed.
In script and arguments of instance_add() uses same Constructor that has no argument, so I need to seprate that executed by instance_add or not.

Why would you need to execute a CTOR/Factory/Init on objects you pass as argument? They already exist.

Anyhow, you could simply use CallerMemberNameAttribute. But that would only work for it to be the "direct" caller. If you need it to scan the entire call stack, we are back to square 1.

First CTOR(instance_add) is for save data to initialize Room. When Room changes, read only datas in List and create new instance for game.
below is a code that I wrote;
`foreach (NV_Object data in _list_init) {
        Type _object = data.GetType();

        NV_Object instance = (NV_Object)Activator.CreateInstance(_object);

...`

Yes that's really rather atypical C#. Are you trying to make deep copies? I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

I'm developing that similar to GameMaker:Studio(GMS) framework. When I want to define the room data in GMS, It uses same methods when need to create new instance in instances's script. Instances has own initializer.  When I defined Room's instance data, I need to use CTOR, but own Initalizer need to not execute (actually instance is not regisetred, just data). When I open that Room, instances are created and registered to game.

The reason why the parameter is an object array is I created primitive instance for system, and developer inherit that instance and create their own Instance. (object is actually primitive instance)

Can you show us the result of st.ToString()?

at ProjectName.PrimitivObject..ctor() at ProjectName.Instance_renderer..ctor() at ProjectName.Loader.load_room_data() at ProjectName.Loader..ctor(ContentManager content) at ProjectName.Main.Initialize() at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize() at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run(GameRunBehavior runBehavior) at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
one of the stacktrace data.

But instance_add doesn't appear in the stacktrace.

Maybe you should have two classes, one for a RoomInstance and one for a RoomData or similar. Seems like your class is doing different things here.

`private void load_room_data() {
    Room room_0 = new Room(640, 480);

    room.Add(room_0);

    room_0.color_background = 0x424b96;//new Color(0, 75, 150);

    room_0.instance_add(

        new InhertedInstance() {
            x = 0, y = 0, depth = 0,
        },
        new InhertedInstance() {
            x = 0, y = 0, depth = 0,
        },...

);`
Room instance room_0 that in load_room_data called instance_add.

I don't understand. Your previous comment shows the stacktrace comes from load_room_data --> Instance_renderer..ctor. How is this Instance_renderer related to your last comment? Is it InhertedInstance? If so, that's not a part of the stacktrace, new InhertedInstance() is just an argument of the method (the constructor is invoked before instance_add is invoked).

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Maybe you're right, Maybe I was trying to implement two other things at once, I'm going to read documents again.

@shingo Instance_renderer is user_defined instance that inherit primitive class. It has some instance data(same as instance_add's argument) in custom initializer.

In fact, original source in documents link, it uses instance_create to create instance. but C# has own constructor system, so I wanted to replace instance_create to constructor.

After a slow second thought, I think I was heading in the wrong direction. Thank you for considering strange questions together.
